# Xamarin.Forms and Android - Getting the result of a toggle button from a different view

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.maps

I have been following the custom pin tutorial using Xamarin.Forms which I have linked below. I have finished implementing it and I have also moved onto adding pins to the map as well through tapping.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/customized-pin

(side note: I am working almost exclusively with Xamarin.Forms and Android)

Currently, I am able to tap on the map and a new custom pin will be added at that location, which is great. What is not great is that I was unable to figure out how to get a tap and long hold gesture to work instead of just the normal tap. To try to combat this, and because I will eventually have to add these anyways, I am planning on adding a button that the user can press to initiate that they want to add a button to the map, and I will later add an undo button, and many others, etc.

The problem is, I have no idea how to get the result of what my toggle button state is from the custom render that I am using for the map. Where can I get the result of my toggle button and use it as a boolean towards whether to add a button or not?

Here is the toggle button code, which I took line by line from their example on this page:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/button

Here is the code where I add a custom pin just by a single tap:

```
    private void GoogleMap_MapClick(object sender, GoogleMap.MapClickEventArgs e)
    {
        ((CustomMap)Element).OnTap(new Position(e.Point.Latitude, e.Point.Longitude));
        var addingPin = new CustomPin
        {
            Type = PinType.Place,
            Position = new Position(e.Point.Latitude, e.Point.Longitude),
            Address = " - need to possibly implement - ",
            Id = "shelter",
            Label = "Pin from tap",
            Url = "http://www.redcross.org"
        };

        Map.Pins.Add(addingPin);
        this.customPins.Add(addingPin);
    }
```

I thought about making a custom button render but by my knowledge I can only apply one Android render to a content page at a time, and when I tried to add a custom button render to the map render then this method was not happy, as it was taking in some sort of Android Map View and not a button view:

```
    protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Map> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            NativeMap.InfoWindowClick -= OnInfoWindowClick;
        }

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            var formsMap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;
            customPins = formsMap.CustomPins;
            Control.GetMapAsync(this);
        }
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Below I have included a pic of what my application looks like so far, along with the custom page that I am using as well.

[image: example]

```
using Hermes.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;

namespace Hermes
{
public class MapPage : ContentPage
{
    public MapPage()
    {
        CustomMap customMap = new CustomMap()
        {
            HeightRequest = 100,
            WidthRequest = 960,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            MapType = MapType.Street,
        };

        var examplePinSupplies = new CustomPin
        {
            Type = PinType.Place,
            Position = new Position(42.02525, -93.65087),
            Address = " - need to possibly implement - ",
            Id = "supplies",
            Label = "supplies",
            Url = "https://www.redcross.org/store"
        };

        var examplePinMedical = new CustomPin
        {
            Type = PinType.Place,
            Position = new Position(42.02290, -93.63912),
            Address = " - need to possibly implement - ",
            Id = "medical",
            Label = "medical",
            Url = "http://www.redcross.org"
        };

        var examplePinShelter = new CustomPin
        {
            Type = PinType.Place,
            Position = new Position(42.02045, -93.60968),
            Address = " - need to possibly implement - ",
            Id = "shelter",
            Label = "shelter",
            Url = "http://www.redcross.org"
        };

        customMap.CustomPins = new List<CustomPin> { examplePinSupplies, examplePinMedical, examplePinShelter };
        customMap.Pins.Add(examplePinSupplies);
        customMap.Pins.Add(examplePinMedical);
        customMap.Pins.Add(examplePinShelter);
        customMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(42.025250, -93.650870), Distance.FromMiles(1.0)));

        var addPin = new ToggleButton { Text = "Add pin" };

        var buttons = new StackLayout
        {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
            Children = {
                addPin
            }
        };

        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Spacing = 0,
            Children = {
                customMap,
                buttons
            }
        };
    }
}
}
```

What I am trying to do: I am trying to tap the 'add pin' toggle button, and then the map will allow me to only add one pin on the map by tapping, and then any other consecutive taps that are not on another pin will not add another pin to the map.

Comment: Maybe this article will be helpful for your logic.https://kampeki-factory.blogspot.com/2015/08/xamarinformsmaps-tap-to-get-position-on.html

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT haha yeah that was the article I used to get tap functionality working. Even though it works, unfortunately it is a bit annoying like I described above. Thanks though

Comment: Can you summarize what exactly do you want your code to do?

Comment: @G.hakim Sorry, I must have glossed over that part. I have included my goals at the end of my question, thanks.

Comment: Haha,How about this logic, when you click the add button, automatically add a pin in the center of the map, you can long press the pin to move it, click pin to customize some methods. But without clicking the add button, the pin will not appear on the map.